# Retrieving applicationContext in Fitnesse test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, fitnesse

I am testing a Spring Controller method with a Fitnesse test.
In the tested class, applicationContext is Autowired (through annotations).
It looks like the autowiring isn't working when the method is called from a Fixture rather than the Spring Framework.
Is there another way to retrieve applicationContext? I can't use the XML file because we are using annotations. I have searched Google for "annotation Spring applicationContext Fitnesse Java", but I didn't find anything.
Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class MySpringController {

@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAllSecurityMaintenanceAllocations/", 
method = {RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity myMethod(@RequestBody final List<String> inList, 
   final  HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

 if (applicationContext == null) {
     System.out.println("applicationContext is null"); 
    }
    //functionality I need to test is in here and is using applicationContext

}
}


public class MyTestFixtureTest extends TableFixture {
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setUp(){

aList.add("foo");
aList.add("foo2");
}
 public void showResults(int fitnessRows){
    MySpringController mySpringController = new MySpringController()
    MockHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    applicationContext = UnitTestConfig.createApplicationContext();
    mySpringController.myMethod(aList, httpServletRequest)
}
}
```

"applicationContext is null" is printing. Does anyone know how to mock autowiring or know another way to get applicationContext in a Fitnesse test?

Comment: While I do not have a particular solution, I would argue that requiring an AppContext (and thus requiring it in a unit test) is the wrong approach. It defeats the purpose of IoC. Are you able to refactor your code so that it does not require the AppContext?

Comment: Not to mention that wiring in app contexts in unit tests makes those unit tests EXTREMELY slow. Not fun if your codebase has thousands of unit tests.

Comment: The problem is that I'm unit testing a method that uses applicationContext. The method uses multiple tables, as do other methods in the application. (Time, user info, reference data, etc.)

Comment: Right, but it is preferable to use the app context to inject your DAOs (etc) into the method's class, so that your method is agnostic of any kind of Spring app context. Then, when you unit test, you can manually inject mocked out DAOs (etc) into the class of the method under test. So there would be no need for an app context in your tests.

Comment: PlatformTransactionmanager  and Environment are also retrieved from applicationContext in myMethod. Should I inject them in the constructor?

Comment: Constructor (or property-setter) should work, since TransactionManager and Environment are beans as well.

Comment: Why are you using FitNesse for a unit test. I would expect you to do either a http call or use selenium to test your controller via FitNesse. If you are looking to do a unit test, why not just use Spring support classes created just to do that (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)?

Comment: We use Selenium for other parts of the code. We are using Fitnesse because it will allow the users to play with the data in the wiki.

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve applicationContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a (static) instance of your applicationContext using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) passing its constructor the annotated classes that define the context your controller should have access to. 
These classes can (of course) be the real configuration your application uses, or a custom configuration for a particular test.

If you'll have multiple tests (i.e. pages) that use the same context it makes sense to have the applicationContext be initialized once (stored in a singleton/static instance) somewhere and have your fixtures retrieve it from there, since creating a context is an expensive operation. A logical place to create the context would be in the SuiteSetUp for these tests.

Comment: Thank you! We did that in a configuration class. We resolved the problem by creating a setter for applicationContext in the controller class and setting it in the Fitnesse fixture when creating the Controller. Thank you.